# Difficulties with textarea on Android

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an html/javascript/css project that i am trying to make an Android application out of. Everything is running fine except for using the  tag in the html file. I have an html file with multiple textarea tags, whenever i run the application and try to tap on the textarea in order to enter the input the focus remains in this textarea and i cannot enter any input in any other textarea's afterwards.

Any help ?

P.S. : I am not very experienced in Android development ...

This is my java code :

```
    package com.ai.shiftpuzzle;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.webkit.WebView;

    public class ShiftPuzzleXOOMActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);


            WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myFiles/main_menu.html");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your issue is related to a documented bug in the Android site : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7189

There is apparently a by-pass that you can try :

```
webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                    v.requestFocus();
                }
                break;
         }
         return false;
    }
});
```